# Chrome giving me wrong margins in printing page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to print a web page this : http://www.gitrama.dz/test/brq.php
and eveytime I try to print it gives me wrong margins . The margins I am using are as follows :

```
body{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 14pt;
     margin:  10mm 10mm 10mm 10mm;

}
 @page {
      size:  9.25in 7in;
      margin:  0;
    }
```

I am using 2 styelsheets and they both have the same characteristics .
you can display the source code of the page and tell me what I did wrong. even when I set margin to zero, it still gives a lot of margins

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What do you mean by "wrong margins"? (Which element? To small? To large? Not working at all?).

Comment: I am getting much bigger margins , even if I set margin to zero I get a big margin 4 ways, http://www.gitrama.dz/test/marg.jpg

Comment: Adjust your printer settings (plus de parametres). Another browser may offer better control of the print settings.

Comment: I have changed the parameters in the printing in the browser(chrome) by setting the margins to 'minimum' and that sort of gives me better results thanks